# How do miniature holograms work?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, technology, hologram

"Miniature" holograms are seen a few times in Star Trek, including the hologram of Tasha Yar, which Data had, and the mini-EMH hologram ("[Virtuoso](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Virtuoso_(episode))").

This technology presumably had some sort of built-in "mobile emitter," which allowed these holograms to operate outside of a holodeck.

I don't understand why the mobile emitter was so amazing to the Voyager crew. The technology existed prior to this discovery, although it was never shown working on a full-size hologram.

Couldn't the technology used for the Tasha Yar hologram simply be adapted for the EMH? Maybe it was impossible for some reason.

Comment: Miniature holograms have no substance. The mobile emitter was, for want of a better phrase "[hard light](http://reddwarf.wikia.com/wiki/Hologram)". That was what made it special.

Comment: At the ends of TNG *Ship in a Bottle* and VOY *Killing Game, Part II* we see the [sort of device](http://i.imgur.com/wDVG9rN.png) that would be required to provide the minimum processing and memory storage necessary to run the Doctor's program, presumably also containing a power supply. Add on to that whatever hardware and power supply would be needed to generate a life size, interactive holographic matrix, and that would be the 24th century mobile emitter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the mobile emitter actually  contained the doctors program as well as a hard light holographic projector

the  mini holograms we see in TNG are basically framed pictures that just happen to use holograms instead of film